# DataSource.initialzie() vs createConnection() in typeorm. Which one to use?

Tags: orm, database-connection, typeorm

I just started using TypeORM as my main ORM for my server. I have seen some tutorials where they use `createConnection()` instead of creating a DataSource object and initializing it.

Are they different? Do they have different use cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`createConnection()` is the old way to do it. Since typeorm 0.3.x  you should use the DataSource object with `DataSource.initialize()`.